# Mips assembly implementing and instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.text
.globl_start:

la $a0,input
lw $t1,0($A0)
li $to,0x00ff00fff
and $t2, $t1, $t0
li $v0, 10
syscall

.data
input: .word 0x12345678
```

Please how can i implement this without the "and" insctruction? Can i use sll or something else?

Comment: Many ways to do that, the simplest would probably be using De Morgan laws to transform the `AND` into `OR` and `NOT` (which is a `XOR` in disguise).

Comment: `(a && b) == !(!a || !b)`. MIPS has NOR instruction which makes it easier to implement that